# Mongodb's Java driver keeps logging message, how to disable it?

Tags: java, mongodb, logging

I am using Mongodb Java Driver 3.4.0-beta, and its 'org.mongodb.driver' keeps logging out messages below:

```
2017-06-28 10:11:37.893  INFO 11700 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 1]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=682055}
2017-06-28 10:11:44.926  INFO 11700 --- [127.0.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 1]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=661572}
2017-06-28 10:11:47.898  INFO 11700 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 1]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=688467}
2017-06-28 10:11:54.931  INFO 11700 --- [127.0.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 1]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=669573}
2017-06-28 10:11:57.902  INFO 11700 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 1]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=688015}
2017-06-28 10:12:04.934  INFO 11700 --- [127.0.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 1]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=658192}
2017-06-28 10:12:07.905  INFO 11700 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 1]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=706180}
2017-06-28 10:12:14.940  INFO 11700 --- [127.0.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 1]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=660184}
2017-06-28 10:12:17.910  INFO 11700 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 1]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=692718}
2017-06-28 10:12:24.945  INFO 11700 --- [127.0.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 1]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=711120}
2017-06-28 10:12:27.914  INFO 11700 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

It's useless information for me and too much verbose. I've searched almost every solution in stackoverflow and none of them works for me. One of them is like:

```
static {
  System.setProperty("DEBUG.MONGO", "false");
  System.setProperty("DB.TRACE", "false");
  LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
  Logger logger = context.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver.cluster");
  logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
}
```

and:

```
static {
  Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver.cluster");
  logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
}
```

By making breakpoints to debug I've figured out that it used `logback` as Logger implementation and but I had no way to get real logger the driver is using, so I cannot set it's log level. Using `Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver.cluster");` actually doesn't work. It just keeps logging out.

I am wondering:

1. How to avoid those messages?
2. Why does mongodb driver log it?(it's totally useless infomation)

Comment: Any particular reason why 3.4.0-beta? There are more stable versions of Mongo 3.4 now.

Comment: @dilsingi Amazing! I switched to 3.4.2 and now disabling the logging works! I used it because I just copied and pasted the dependencies from the installation guide of [document](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/getting-started/installation/) and not thinking it's an version issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Question: in which file would one add the above static block to disable logging?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use beta version then set it's log level:

```
static {
  Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver.cluster");
  logger.setLevel(Level.WARN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this line

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE);
```